# Multithreading problem (how to know when to stop) - multiple threads working on a same static double variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-sleep

I have a class named Juice which has this variable:

```
private static double REMAINING_JUICE = 100d;
```

And I have a function called `adjustJuice` which creates a new thread. Makes the thread sleep for 2 seconds and then decrements the above static variable value by a random amount.

Now I want to keep calling `adjustJuice` from my main method - but halt when there is no juice left.

Since all the threads are working on the same variable - and I don't know by how much amount will my juice be decremented. How do I create a loop in my main function which halts at this condition?

Comment: Check the value value before decrementing.  If <= 0 then quit, else decrement

Comment: How do I know how many threads to create? I can put this condition of checking if REMAINING_JUICE <= 0 and not do anything on if it is true. But how I do communicate this to the for loop which is creating the thread?

Comment: It's an impossible task. If the value is reduced by a random amount 2 seconds in the future, then it's impossible to know if there will be anything left, because we haven't yet invented a way to look into the future.

Comment: Look at the problem this way - "I want to create a new thread only when the previous thread/threads have finished updating the juice amount". How do I implement this?

Comment: I think you method adjustJuice will be like this ..    class Juice{
 private static double REMAINING_JUICE = 100d;
 public void adjustJuis() {
  synchronized (Juice.class) {
   if(Juice.REMAINING_JUICE <= 0) {
    return;
   }else {
    //create thread
    //thread sleep 2 second
    //decrement with random amount
   }
  }
 }
}